# Disable Tab.Navigation screen change when using ScrollView inside Screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have an implementatition like:

```
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-top-tabs';
const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

// ...

<Tab.Navigation>
  <Tab.Screen title="example" component={WithTabNav} />
  <Tab.Screen title="another" component={RegularView} />
</Tab>
```

And the implementation for `WithTabNav` is essentially:

```
<View>
  <ScrollView horizontal>
    // Here I have a list of buttons that in total go past screen width
  </ScrollView>
</View>
```

Otherwise it works as expected, but when I reach the end of `ScrollView` it will also scroll away from the `WithTabNav` component to the other navigation Tab.

How can I prevent that behaviour? So no matter where, or how many times you drag the `ScrollView` inside `WithTabNav` component, it would not scroll to the other component (`RegularView`) in the `Tab.Navigation`?

ScrollView only seems to listen to `tabPress` and `tabLongPress`, but not for example something like `dragEnd` or `viewEnd` or anything like that that would tell that I have dragged the `ScrollView` to the end of it, where I could then use eg. `event.preventDefault()` or such.

Obviously it should still scroll if I drag from outside of `ScrollView` area.

Comment: Not a real solution, but one thing to explore is `<Tab.Navigator screenOptions={{ swipeEnabled: false }}>`. This however prevents any kind of scrolling between navigation tabs. But maybe it could be utilized to conditionally enable/disable scrolling.